# Microsoft Teams Webhook returning strange Cosmos error

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

Since a few days ago, the Microsoft Teams webhooks are returning strange errors.

> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

We are not using Cosmos but are only sending a message card to the webhook, as we've done forever without changing anything.

This is our request:

```
curl -X POST https://aworkio.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/fd4d3ece-XXX@03df4317-XXX/01ea66d6-XXX/1b858b66XXX/fd5b2231XXX"
-d '{"@type":"MessageCard","@context":"https://schema.org/extensions","summary":"\uD83D\uDCAC <b>Sebastian commented</b> on <a href='https://support.awork.io/tasks/9a03bef1-XXX/details'>New Comment</a>","themeColor":"85A0C6","title":"\uD83D\uDCAC <b>Sebastian commented</b> on <a href='https://support.awork.io/tasks/9a03bef1-XXX/details'>New Comment</a>","sections":[{"text":"<p>Comment</p>"}]}'
```

The webhook URL was created by Microsoft Teams when configuring the integration.

I expect this request to succeed or to receive an actionable error message.

Comment: I'm not seeing any auth header in the request, let alone signed. Based on the error message, it seems an auth header is mandatory. This question is a better fit for MS support team, assuming you're paying them for Enterprise support.

Comment: We tried this at our end by modifying the payload you have shared. The card got posted without any error.
 
Card - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNvdr.png

Comment: Payload -  curl -X POST -d "{ '@type': 'MessageCard', '@context': 'https://schema.org/extensions', 'summary':'\uD83D\uDCAC <b>Summary test</b> on', 'themeColor': '#00FF00', 'title': '\uD83D\uDCAC <b>Sebastian commented</b> on', 'sections':[{'text': '<p>Comment</p>'}]}" https://m365xxxxxx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/8778fe07-0600-4540-8a51-6390a6278287@36a708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-0a5f7b7693df/IncomingWebhook/fbeeb858fa704ea8a29258a81dd7ca74/4ebcc4d0-291b-4154-a85f-a89cd77aefa8

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar as far as I know the authentication information is contained in the URL in the form of a token, no other authentication needed for the webhooks as they are generated by Teams. At least it has worked that way for several months. Additionally, I would expect a 401 or similar response with a proper error message if this was the case, not a weird Cosmos error message which seems like it's something Teams internal.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT but your webhook URL is also different, so I assume Teams generated it differently. I've just tried it again and we always get the same URL. We use the Javascript SDK hosted at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.12.1/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js to interact with Teams in an iFrame during setup and get the URL from the settings Callback:
```microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function(settings) {
            console.log('Webhook url: ' + settings.webhookUrl)
}
```

Comment: We will check this and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: An ICM has been raised for this issue. We will keep you posted on the progress. Thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT it seems like it's working again. Was anything changed on your end?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no, it sometimes work and sometimes fails.

Comment: Team is working on the fix, we will keep you posted once the fix is rolled out completely. Thank you.

Comment: This issue has been fixed, could you please verify the fix. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT it looks like it's working again for us. Thanks